# Is there anyway to create Javascript object with "default function"? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, object

As you may know, AngularJS `$http` service is allowing to call it with/out specific function, for ex:

1. `$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});`
2. `$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

I would like to get some more information about the way I can implement it on my factory and generally in JS.

Comment: If question is more about how to architecture angular data retrieval - check the $resource - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: To me it seems more like you asking about how to implement callbacks. Is that what you asking?

Comment: @dvir thanks, I've got an answer by Shreyas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are Objects in JavaScript. This means that you can assign other properties and functions on a function.

```
function foo(){
   //do something
}

foo.bar = function(){
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! make sense. 

Example for z0r:

`var a = function(){
    alert('main');
}
a.foo = function(){
  alert('bar');
}
a(); a.foo();`

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned above you can implement what you want using Angular's '$resource'. Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
app.service('testResource', ['$resource',  function ($resource) {
    var apiBaseUrl = 'http://test-backend/api';
    var testResource = $resource(
        apiBaseUrl + '/test/'
        {},
        {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        }
    );
    this.getAll = function () {
        return testResource
            .query()
            .$promise
            .then(function (data) {
                var tests = [];
                angular.forEach(data[0], function (value) {
                    tests.push(value);
                });
                return tests;
            });
    };
}]);
```

Then inject it in Controller (or wherever) and call it:

```
testResource.getAll().then(
                        function (data) {
                            $scope.tests = data;
                        }
                    );
```

You can also implement other methods such as POST, PUT, DELETE.